# data-disable-with attribute is activated for all buttons when any form button is pressed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a form with 2 buttons for different actions, each one is executed correctly but when any of 2 is clicked both buttons change to the loading state while the page its loading.

```
 <%= button_tag(:name => "commit", :value => "finish_evaluation",:class => "btn btn-primary ", data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?', disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x'></i> <span class='fa5-text fa-2x'> loading...</span>"}) do %>
     <%= fa_icon('save', text: ' finish evaluation', size: '2x') %>
 <% end %>

 <%= button_tag(:name => "commit", :value => "pause_evaluation",:class => "btn btn-primary ", data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?', disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x'></i> <span class='fa5-text fa-2x'> loading...</span>"}) do %>
     <%= fa_icon('save', text: ' pause evaluation', size: '2x') %>
 <% end %>
```

I attach images of the buttons before and after clicking any:

[image]

[image]

How could I correct it so that I only change the button that is clicked when submitting the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That has been an issue since before rails-ujs was merged into ActionView as [documented here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/257). Technically you can override [Rails.disableElement](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/features/disable.coffee#L25), but your best bet would be to just have one submit button.